# AND/OR comparisons starting from null, true, or false..?

Tags: php

I want to loop through a set of conditions, returning true only if every condition is met, collecting reasons along the way if not.

```
<?php
$dataval = 0;
$tests = [
    [1,0,0,4,5],
    [0,0,0,0,0]
];
foreach($tests as $condition) {
    $retval = null;
    $reasons = [];
    foreach($condition as $item){
       if($item == $dataval){
        $retval == $retval && true;
        } else {
            $retval == $retval && false;
            $reasons[] = "Failed to match " . $dataval . " to " . $item;
        }
    }
    if($retval === true){
        echo "All conditions met<br>";
    } else {
        echo "NOT all conditions met<br>";
    }
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($reasons, 1) . "</pre>";
}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
NOT all conditions met
Array
(
    [0] => Failed to match 0 to 1
    [1] => Failed to match 0 to 4
    [2] => Failed to match 0 to 5
)
NOT all conditions met
Array
(
)
```

No matter what the initial value of $retval, one or both tests is going to fail. If the initial value is true, both tests return true (which is incorrect); if false or null, then both return false (which is also incorrect).

Yes, I *could* break on the first false, but *why* the test failed is important, and it could fail for more than one reason so I shouldn't just break out of the loop as soon as the first failure is caught.

Is there a way to do this without adding another variable to tally up the hits and misses?

Comment: `$retval == $retval && true;` can't be right, you maybe want `$retval = $retval && true;` instead to actually change the variable `$retval`.

Comment: And `$retval == $retval && false;` would just be `$retval = false;`

Comment: Since `$retval` is initially `null`, it can never become `true` when you use `&&` to assign the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `$retval` to `true`. When you get a mismatch, set it to `false` and push the error onto the `$reason` array.

But don't really need the `$retval` variable. Just check if the array is empty.

```
foreach($tests as $condition) {
    $reasons = [];
    foreach($condition as $item){
       if($item != $dataval) {
            $reasons[] = "Failed to match " . $dataval . " to " . $item;
        }
    }
    if(empty($reasons)){
        echo "All conditions met<br>";
    } else {
        echo "NOT all conditions met<br>";
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($reasons, 1) . "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I was overthinking it. Sometimes it just needs an extra pair of eyes. Thanks.